# How to validate the Given date is not a Future date in mule 3

Tags: mule, mule-component, mulesoft, mule-esb

My requirement is to validate Given date should not be a Future date.

For example the `today date is 01/01/2020` .

Input date :

```
30/01/2020
```

Output :

```
Date should not be Future date.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Get the current date by `#[server.dateTime]` .

2.Set the Transform message.

```
"datevalidation": (payload.DateOfBirth as :date {format:"yyyy-MM-dd"}) < (flowVars.currentdate as :date {format:"yyyy-MM-dd"}
```

3.Add validation component `isTure` .

```
<validation:is-true config-ref="Validation_Configuration" expression="#[payload.datevalidation]" doc:name="Validation" message="date should not be Future."/>
```

Full Code.

```
<mule xmlns:validation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/validation" xmlns:dw="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/validation http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/validation/current/mule-validation.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <validation:config name="Validation_Configuration" doc:name="Validation Configuration"/>
    <flow name="helloFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/hello" allowedMethods="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <set-variable variableName="currentdate" value="#[server.dateTime]" doc:name="current date Variable"/>
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
{
    "datevalidation": (payload.DateOfBirth as :date {format:"yyyy-MM-dd"}) < (flowVars.currentdate as :date {format:"yyyy-MM-dd"})
}]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <validation:is-true config-ref="Validation_Configuration" expression="#[payload.datevalidation]" doc:name="Validation" message="date should not be Future."/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Hope its Help.

Answer (score 3):

You can also just compare them as Dates using equality operators.. if your dates have times make sure you're converting things to a common timezone for those edge cases.

For mule 3:

```
%dw 1.0
%input payload application/json
%output application/json
%function isFutureDate(dt) (dt as :date) > (now as :date)

%var dt = "30/01/2020" as :date { format: "dd/MM/yyyy" }
---
isFuture: isFutureDate(dt)
```

For mule 4:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
fun isFutureDate(dateToTest: Date | DateTime) =
    (dateToTest as Date) > (now() as Date)

var date = |2021-06-10|
---
isFutureDate(date)
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternate suggestion

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var inpDate = "08/06/2021" as Date {"format": "dd/MM/yyyy"}
var today= now() as Date {"format": "dd/MM/yyyy"} 
---
if (daysBetween(inpDate,today) > 0) "PastDate" else "FutureDate"
```